# Logo image is not pushing to the top left of navigation

Tags: html, css

I would like to push the logo image to top left, `center` of Navigation, right now it looks like that it has slipped out from Navigation.

If I reduce the height and width of the image to `50px`, then it is kind of displaying inside navigation but then I can't read the logo text.

Expected :Assume the yellow round is image, I would like to display like this:

[image]

[image]

```
.wrapper{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 position:relative;
}

#wrap{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
.siteNavigation_nav_links{
    padding: 1.75rem 0;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 0 #e6e6e6;  
    background-color: #e8eaeb;  
    padding-right:50px;
}
.clublogomain{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -20px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
```

`Navigation.js`

```
<div className="App">
            <div className="wrapper">
                <div id="wrap">
                    <nav className="siteNavigation_nav_links">
                        <div className="row" style={divStyle}><img className="clublogomain"src="images/SSSLogo.png"></img></div>
                        <NavLink className="mobile_register_link" to="/">Home</NavLink>
                        <NavLink className="mobile_login_link" to="/login" onClick={logout}>Logout</NavLink>
                        <span className="image_login_link">
                            <img className="nav_profile" onClick={()=>setShowMenu(!showMenu)} src={imgData}></img>
                        </span>
                   </nav>
             </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, when I retrieve your code, the image is located well to the left, can you give me more informations?

Comment: I think we might be missing some of the styling - are you using React? I usually find adding an outline to elements lets me see what's going on with the positioning a bit more easily. Trying div {outline:1px solid #f00} might help.

Comment: I would like to move the image slightly left top of the navigation

Comment: Yes using Reactjs

Comment: @Caro, I have updated the question with the expected look. It is displaying left which is fine, but more 50% of the image pushed to bottom. I would like to display left center of the Nav..

Comment: .siteNavigation_nav_links   you use  align-items: center and justify-content: space-between but i don't see display: flex;  ?

Comment: When i use display flex, the image looks better, but all other links like Home, Logout got pushed to left side. Home, Logout and other link need to display right hand side of the Navigation.